# Automatic sliding gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to find a sliding gallery that automatically slides. I am not sure how to get this gallery to slide automatically on page load.

http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx

Demo: http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGalleryDemo1.htm

I aml ooking for something like that but i am using this one currently at the moment, but i am also trying to find a way to automatically scroll it when it loads.

Either this or i need a new script that works the same exact way.

Does anyone know of a script?

Comment: There are tons of plug-in out there..
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

Comment: Yeah i need something with the same functionality as the one i found though that automatically scrolls that is why im stuck right now

Comment: You can modify that one quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FlexSlider](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) is actually pretty great! Built in jQuery, fully responsible, usable on touch devices - and with an autostart option as you wished:

Here are the features presented on the website:

- Simple, semantic markup
- Supported in all major browsers
- Horizontal/vertical slide and fade animations
- Multiple slider support, Callback API, and more
- Hardware accelerated touch swipe support
- Custom navigation options
- Use any html elements in the slides
- Built for beginners and pros, alike
- Free to use under the MIT license

-> http://flex.madebymufffin.com/

Comment: It needs to go from small to big like in the example i showed.